# WPFToastNotification click event

Tags: c#, wpf, toast

I'm developing a windows application in that I've a requirement of showing notification and when the user clicks on that notification it should navigate to that page based on the arguments.

Currently,The notification is showing. I am using WPFNotification Nuget package to achieve this. Here is my code to load notification:

```
INotificationDialogService _dailogService = new NotificationDialogService();

var newNotification = new Notification()
{
    Title = "New Message from ",
    Message = "123",
    ImgURL = "/icon.png",
};

var notificationConfiguration = new NotificationConfiguration(
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3),
    1000,
    500,
    "Notification",
    NotificationFlowDirection.RightBottom
);

_dailogService.ShowNotificationWindow(newNotification);
```

It is the method to show the notification. Now,I need to have a click event for that notification. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

To get a click event you need to have access to the window poped up. Unfortunately a look in the public source code shows that the windows created [are collected private](https://github.com/muhammad-magdy/WPFToastNotification/blob/master/1.0/WPFNotification/WPFNotification/Core/NotifyBox.cs#L34).

But it is possible to use the public function `WPFNotification.Core.NotifyBox.Show` by defining your own custom window. You could use the [default implementation](https://github.com/muhammad-magdy/WPFToastNotification/blob/master/1.0/WPFNotification/WPFNotification/Core/NotifyBox.cs#L64) in your code and extend it with the click event subscription like:

```
public static void Show(object content, NotificationConfiguration configuration)
{
    DataTemplate notificationTemplate = (DataTemplate)Application.Current.Resources[configuration.TemplateName];
    Window window = new Window()
    {
        Title = "",
        Width = configuration.Width.Value,
        Height = configuration.Height.Value,
        Content = content,
        ShowActivated = false,
        AllowsTransparency = true,
        WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None,
        ShowInTaskbar = false,
        Topmost = true,
        Background = Brushes.Transparent,
        UseLayoutRounding = true,
        ContentTemplate = notificationTemplate
    };

    //Subscribe to clicks
    window.PreviewMouseDown += NotificationWindow_PreviewMouseDoubleClick;

    WPFNotification.Core.NotifyBox.Show(
        window, configuration.DisplayDuration, configuration.NotificationFlowDirection);
}

private static void NotificationWindow_PreviewMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Clicked!!!");
}
```

Now you are able to show the notification like

```
Show(newNotification, notificationConfiguration);
```

Note that you need to add the template resources like described in the [getting started](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1073989/WPF-Toast-Notification) to show a default styled popup.

```
<ResourceDictionary>
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
   <ResourceDictionary Source="/WPFNotification;component/Assets/NotificationUI.xaml"/>
  </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

If the template `"Notification"` you specified is not available, just use the default one `NotificationConfiguration.DefaultConfiguration.TemplateName`.

Comment: Thank you for the help @Fruchtzwerg,But it is throwing an exception at this statement  
DataTemplate notificationTemplate =(DataTemplate)Application.Current.Resources[configuration.TemplateName];

saying that  The resource 'Notification' is not present in the dictionary.

any idea??

Comment: Looks like you forgot to define the correct template. I've added some information to my answer.